# What are the privileges needed for a user to vote in elections?

Tags: discussion, election

I'm wondering about voting system.

Anybody can vote for a candidate in elections?

Are there some privileges or needs for so?

If no, How can you protect the election from fake accounts?!

Comment: I think there no requirements to elect. The only needed requirement is 300 reputation to nominate yourself

Comment: @kamil: There is actually a limit of 150 rep to vote in the primary and election phases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the right sidebar (under the stats) of the ['Election' phase tab of the election page](https://askubuntu.com/election?tab=election):

> In the **election** phase, up to 10 candidates advance to final community
>   voting. Any community member with **150** reputation may vote in the
>   election.

It is the same for the ['Primary' phase](https://askubuntu.com/election?tab=primary):

> In the **primary** phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community
>   voting. Any community member with **150** reputation may vote in the
>   primary.

Comment: Thanks for quick response and your explanation